# Automatically inputting next different date R

Tags: r, loops, date, datetime

Here is my sample..

```
Raw_Data2$Game_Date
2019-06-14
2019-06-14
2019-06-14
2019-06-19
2019-06-22
2019-07-01
2019-07-01
2019-07-01
2019-07-04
```

I am trying to write code that will automatically input the next different date in sequence into this code..

```
 Player1 = Raw_Data2[Raw_Data2$game_date == "2019-06-14", ]
```

After a function, any function, has been run. I want the date to change automatically to the next different date in the column. Is there a way to do that?

Secondly, I want to complete this function:

```
 Days.Rest <- as.numeric(date2 - date1)
```

Where "date2" is the day being used in the code for

```
  Player1 = Raw_Data2[Raw_Data2$game_date == "2019-06-14", ]
```

during that specific loop, and "date1" is the previous different day in the sample.

Comment: Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: Expected output for first would be the first date, then change the date to next different date.. run line of code, leads to "2019-06-14" being put in as X

                Player1 = Raw_Data2[Raw_Data2$game_date == X, ]

second line of code switches X to next different date, which with the sample data would be "2019-06-19" so that on a repeat loop of the function it runs 2019-06-19 as the date....

Comment: I just want to take the first date, and put it in for the date in the player1 code... then I wanna take the next unique date and put it in.. then the next unique date and next... I just can't do it manually because there is too many dates.